# Is it possible to switch backend language for an appengine app?

Tags: google-app-engine

I can test this but I don't know if it's possible. I run a gae app with backend python. If I want to change language to Go, Java or PHP, can I keep my app and my data and just deploy a complete new version of my app that uses another SDK and another language instead of my current choice? Or do I have to create a new app and maybe migrate data?

Comment: *I can test this but I don't know if it's possible* you could find out by testing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Each module or even version could be written on any language you want while working with same data.