# How to repurpose a Google App Engine python app to Golang

Tags: python, go

I have a python Google App Engine app with a custom domain name but now I want to change that app to be implemented in Go rather than python.
Must I completely delete the python app first or is there a less destructive approach to loading Go source code to replace the python source code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change runtime from Python to Go in App Engine standard environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49831512/change-runtime-from-python-to-go-in-app-engine-standard-environment).  See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/32316257/12258482

Comment: `gcloud app deploy` the Go version over  the Python version. Ne delete required.